# rcpp function calling another rcpp function

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm guessing this is an easy question, but I'm new to Cpp, and am stuck.

I've created a function in R, using Rcpp and:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
```

I can call the function in R and it works as intended.  Let's call it `F1`.

Next, I want to create another function, `F2`, using `Rcpp` which calls the first function.  I use standard function call language (i.e., `F1(arguments))`, and it compiles fine through R when I use `sourceCpp()`.

But when I try to call `F2` in R, I get:

> Error in .Primitive(".Call")(

and

> F2 is missing

The first `.cpp` file contains

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double F1(NumericVector a) {
  int n = a.size();
  double result=0;  // create output vector
  double ss = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    ss += pow(a[i],2);
  }

  result = ss;
  return result;
}
```

The following is in another .cpp file.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double F2(NumericVector a) {
  double result=0;

  result = F1(a);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: This is vague. Please show the code you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you are trying to do now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. What you do here would not work in plain C++ either has the second C++ file has no declaration of F1. Typically, one would have common declarations in a header.  What Romain showed in his answer works, but must be considered a hack.  Learn about multi-file C++ projects.  Or keep things in one file.

Comment: You can actually create the header file for the first script, say `first.h` and write `#include "a.h"` in the second cpp file to import the functions in the first.  Usually, "a.h" declares the signature of the functions and "a.cpp" implements it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just put both functions in the same `.cpp` file, or start working on a package.

If you stick to separate `.cpp` files, then `F2` does not know about F1. You can call back `F1` as an R function, but that's not going to be as efficient and you will have to deal with converting outputs to a double, etc ...

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double F2(NumericVector a) {
  double result=0;

  // grab the R function F1
  Function F1( "F1" ) ; 
  result = as<double>( F1(a) );

  return result;
}
```

But really create a package or put all your functions in the same `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 5):

Couple of points:

- Rcpp Attributes is *not* the only way to export C++ functions to R.
- Rcpp Attributes renames functions, use the `verbose=TRUE` argument and see the result. These functions names are randomized but ...
- Rcpp Attributes has an export-to-C++ ability, see `Rcpp::interfaces()` in the vignette.

So if you want to stick with Attributes that seems to be one way.  Else call the function you want to call `fworker()`, have `f1()` call it (and `f1()` becomes available in R) and have `f2()` call `fworker()`.  But you should be able to do better.

Otherwise, you can of course fall back to manually exporting the function using an explicitly created R wrapper.