# Calling an Rcpp function in another rcpp script in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm guessing this is an easy question but I'm new to using CPP in R. I created an cpp function in a cpp file in R, say mean(a, b) using #include <Rcpp.h> and // [[Rcpp::export]] and sourceCpp to use that function in the rest of my R script. This works fine.
I am trying to also use that function in another Cpp function file. It seems to be possible using #include <mean.h> but I don't understand the logic/way of doing that.
How do I have to change my mean function script to have this work if this is possible ?

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::double mean(int a, int b) 
{ 
double mean = 0;
mean = (a+b)/2;
return mean 
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745735/rcpp-function-calling-another-rcpp-function ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527719/calling-a-rcpp-function-from-another-rcpp-function-while-building-an-r-package

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate as we taught how to _use a package_ here for years.