# how to call a function created in Rcpp from another Rccp function

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to run an Rcpp function esat in the function h_evap. Both are in a common .cpp file and I execute it with sourceCPP in Rstudio. Here's the code. Both esat and h_evap are created and esat works fine. But h_evap gives me the output

```
> esat(42)
[1] 256.7082
> h_evap(42)
Error in h_evap(42) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=closure; target=double].
```

I suspect the problem is in how I try to access esat from the global environment but can't figure out how to call esat to get the value of the output rather than a closure.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

    NumericVector esat(NumericVector Tk) {
      NumericVector esat_out(Tk.size(), NAN);
      for (size_t i=0; i<Tk.size(); i++) {
        esat_out[i] = 6.1121 * Tk[i];
      }
      return esat_out;
    }
    
    // [[Rcpp::export]]
    NumericVector h_evap(NumericVector Tk) {
      Environment env = Environment::global_env();
      NumericVector f_esat = env["esat"];
      NumericVector h_evap_out(Tk.size(), NAN);
      for (size_t i=0; i<Tk.size(); i++) {
        
        h_evap_out[i] = (313.15 - Tk[i]);
        h_evap_out[i] = h_evap_out[i] + f_esat(Tk[i]);
      }

  return h_evap_out;
}

/*** R
h_evap(42)
*/
```

An alternative is to use cppFunction. I've tried that and still get errors that are not clear to this Rcpp novice. Here's the code

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('NumericVector esat(NumericVector Tk) {
  NumericVector esat_out(Tk.size(), NAN);
  for (size_t i=0; i<Tk.size(); i++) {
    esat_out[i] = 6.1121 * Tk[i];
  }
  return esat_out;
}')

cppFunction('NumericVector h_evap(NumericVector Tk) {
   NumericVector h_evap_out(Tk.size(), NAN);
  for (size_t i=0; i<Tk.size(); i++) {
    h_evap_out[i] = esat(Tk[i]);
  }
  return h_evap_out;
}')
```

esat compiles fine. h_evap returns an error message is not clear to me...

Comment: Shouldn't the line be `Function f_esat = env["esat"];`

Comment: That returns `testSimplefun.cpp:21:35: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('typename storage_type<14>::type' (aka 'double') and 'SEXP' (aka 'SEXPREC *'))`

Comment: sorry, i didn't test your script.  I thought it is a Function instead of NumericVector

Comment: esat is a function, created in the first set of code. It returns a vector. I'm just trying to get the results of esat(Tk[i] on the line h_evap... in the second function h_evap.

Comment: My issue is the sourceCpp is giving errors to test

Comment: Don't use `sourceCpp()`.  Create a package.  We said so hundreds of times and it is still true.

Comment: I am a long ways from creating a package, although that is the ultimate goal. Right now, I'm trying to create a simplified version of the code that reproduces the problem of getting one Rccp function called by another. Is there an alternative to sourceCpp to do the testing?

Comment: Why are you trying to grab `esat` from the global environment? If the functions are in the same .cpp file just call `esat` directly in `h_evap`.  relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745735/rcpp-function-calling-another-rcpp-function

Comment: I looked at 19745735 earlier but didn't seem quite the same. I have tried replacing `h_evap_out[i] = h_evap_out[i] + f_esat(Tk[i]);` with `h_evap_out[i] = h_evap_out[i] + esat(Tk[i]);` and removing calling it from the global environment. I get this error message `testSimplefun.cpp:24:28: error: assigning to 'typename storage_type<14>::type' (aka 'double') from incompatible type 'typename traits::enable_if<traits::is_convertible<typename traits::remove_const_and_reference<double>::type, typename traits::storage_type<14>::type>::value, typename sugar::Plus_Vector_Primitive<14, true, V...`

Comment: Because I'm stubborn I tried cppFunction, which also failed. I am now bowing to the Rcpp god and his point that is obvious once said ("Nowhere does it say that these are callable from C++."). I will go to the build package route. And thanks for perservering!

Comment: There are different tools for different purposes.  `cppFunction()` has its uses, as has `sourceCpp()`.  But ultimately you want a package.   And it _really_ is not any harder.

Comment: I now have a package. At least I have a folder created by `library(Rcpp)
Rcpp.package.skeleton("wbgtInC", example_code = FALSE,
                      cpp_files = c("R/cpp/wbgtFunctions.cpp"))
compileAttributes(pkgdir = "wbgtInC", verbose = getOption("verbose"))` Now what do I do with it?  :-)

Comment: You may have come across `R CMD build` and `R CMD INSTALL` before, or if you haven't, their equivalent buttons in RStudio, or `devtools` idioms, or whatever else people do these days to avoid the documented usage :)   Kidding aside I usually just call `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` with the package name (no extra args), copy the source file in and take it from there.  In manual builds you need `compileAttributes()`, if you use RStudio instead it does it for you.  We documented this in many tutorials and workshops, maybe some existing slides can help.

Comment: There are so many Dirk Eddelbuettel tutorials and workshops it is hard to find what one is looking for! I am a relative newbie to R and Rstudio. I see these vague references from last century to R CMD build and R CMD INSTALL but try to avoid learning about them! I live in Rstudio.

Comment: Sure, it's your call to paint yourself into whichever corner you prefer.  But many of our Rcpp tutorials also show how to build packages with Rcpp within RStudio.  I offer these as a free service, if they don't work for you there is a money back guarantee and can you try something else. It's a big world.

Comment: Another problem you have is that `esat(NumericVector Tk)` expects a vector but you try to call with a scalar:  `... + f_esat(Tk[i]);`  That can't work.  I often find it helps to walk before trying to run or sprint.  Try doing things incrementally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight rewrite of your file *to avoid calling a C++ via an intermediate R function* which is (generally) a bad idea and almost always an uncalled-for and heavy tax on performance.

As you defined *a valid C++ function* in the same file *and before its use* (so that you don't need a signature to declare it as e.g. a header file would do for you) can simply call it.

I also changed the loop index variable to get rid of one warning during compilation, and, while I was at it, removed `using namespace Rcpp;` and switched to explicit calls with namespace which is more explicit and a little 'safer' from surprises in larger code bases.

*Edit:* And as your loops are in fact invariant to the loop index,
we can rewrite the code as *vectorized* calls whicg is shorter, simpler, faster, and easier to reason with.  (And could, of course, be done from R too...)

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector esat(Rcpp::NumericVector Tk) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector esat_out(Tk.size(), NAN);
    for (R_xlen_t i=0; i<Tk.size(); i++) {
        esat_out[i] = 6.1121 * Tk[i];
    }
    return esat_out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector h_evap(Rcpp::NumericVector Tk) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector h_evap_out(Tk.size(), NAN);
    Rcpp::NumericVector f_out = esat(Tk);
    for (R_xlen_t i=0; i<Tk.size(); i++) {
        h_evap_out[i] = (313.15 - Tk[i]);
        h_evap_out[i] = h_evap_out[i] + f_out[i];
    }
    return h_evap_out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector esatV(Rcpp::NumericVector Tk) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector esat_out = 6.1121 * Tk;
    return esat_out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector h_evapV(Rcpp::NumericVector Tk) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector f_out = esatV(Tk);
  Rcpp::NumericVector h_evap_out = 313.15 - Tk + f_out;
  return h_evap_out;
}

/*** R
esat(42)
h_evap(42)
esatV(42)
h_evapV(42)
*/
```

#### Usage

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/68605528/answer.cpp")

> esat(42)
[1] 256.708

> h_evap(42)
[1] 527.858

> esatV(42)
[1] 256.708

> h_evapV(42)
[1] 527.858
>
```

Answer (score 0):

With some judicious study of various stack overflow Qs and As and a few key tips from Dirk, the following code seems to do what I want. Two key points - use of Function and writing the output of esat into a NumericVector and reading that into h_evap. I'm still doing a package...

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

NumericVector esat(NumericVector Tk) {
  NumericVector esat_out(Tk.size(), NAN);
  for (size_t i=0; i<Tk.size(); i++) {
    esat_out[i] = 6.1121 * Tk[i];
  }
  return esat_out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector h_evap(NumericVector Tk) {
  Environment env = Environment::global_env();
  Function f_esat = env["esat"];
  NumericVector h_evap_out(Tk.size(), NAN);
  NumericVector f_out = f_esat(Tk);
  for (size_t i=0; i<Tk.size(); i++) {

    h_evap_out[i] = (313.15 - Tk[i]);
    h_evap_out[i] = h_evap_out[i] + f_out[i];
  }

  return h_evap_out;
}

/*** R
esat(42)
h_evap(42)
*/
```

Comment: Don't call `esat` via an `Rcpp::Environment`.  That will kill a solid chunk of performance. Really.  You do want, as per you question, a C++ function calling a C++ function _without going through an R function_.

Comment: Not sure if you saw my answer but it improves in two aspects on your answer here (which was helpful in spelling a complete and reproducible example out).

Comment: I not only saw it this morning but am both implementing elements of it in my larger code and realizing some other things to do that will make my code cleaner and hopefully quicker. All functions are now vectorized, the order of functions in the cpp file has been redone to eliminate the need to read from the global environment, including some constants I had been doing that with. So a big thanks for your answer! I will say that it is a bit depressing to get a glimpse of how much power is potentially out there and how little I know about accessing it. Also, got rid of namespace Rcpp.

Comment: Awesomesauce. It is all, as always, a little overwhelming in both complexities and capacities.  So take things at a time.  Small steps help too, especially once adds a few of those up.

Comment: Net net we where both confused by a simple logic / hence compiler error (your 'scalar where vector expected') which threw your initial compilation off.  Baby steps.  Best way to proceed sanely one check at a time...

Comment: Good advice but can be hard to follow... FYI, I get the same message from Robert Hijmans of raster/terra fame. I learn from the masters.